# How to make mutable reference to a struct in Swift

Tags: swift

I have an optional struct and a helper function that creates the struct when needed, and adds data to that struct.

So inside that function I know the value exists, but I need to force unwrap each time I access it:

```
someStruct!.someField1 += value1
someStruct!.someField2 += value2
...
```

What I'd like to do is something like

```
if let someStruct = someStruct {
    someStruct.someField1 += value1
    someStruct.someField2 += value2
    ...
}
```

which obviously doesn't work, as the `someStruct` is treated as copy inside that block. Using `var` also doesn't help since it just makes a mutable copy. What I'd like to have is something like `inout`, but so far I couldn't find any way to achieve it in a simple form.

The only working way I found is adding one more function level, for example:

```
func fillStruct(_ someStruct : inout SomeStruct) {
    someStruct.someField1 += value1
    someStruct.someField2 += value2
    ...
}

fillStruct(&someStruct!)
```

which seems like something unnecessarily complicated, and I'm not sure how well it will be optimized.

So, is there a way to have a mutable reference to a struct using some `if let` -like syntax?

Comment: If you’re changing the state, why not use a class instead of a struct?

Comment: Because this actually is a data type, and I'm going to have a lot of them - in which case I'd rather avoid having he objects scattered in memory

Comment: someStruct?.someField1 += value1 should also work, right?